# Google API's client library for Java 1.6.0-beta, correct dependencies / jars for using with Android?

Tags: google-api-java-client

Firstly, since there has been a number of updates to the Google API's client library for Java can someone please confirm what the correct jars / maven dependencies now are from an Android app dev perspective?

I started out looking at the Google Tasks API example [link below] as documented against v1.4.1-beta of the above library.

http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/articles/oauth-and-tasks-on-android.html

Using 1.6.0-beta dependencies with Maven, ADT 16, Eclipse Indigo and m2e-android causes compile errors which result from some of the 3rd party dependencies that this library relies upon.

I initially raised my compile woes with the Maven Android Developers Google Group [link below] which kindly highlighted these issues and points to a requirement for some API's such as httpclient to be declared with a provided scope in the parent pom.

http://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c98d8074a6c34e8f

Raising this here initially as suggested in the Google Code home for the above library as it would be good to gain clarification on my opening question but please also advise if I should post this somewhere else to raise the above as an issue.

Kind regards
Jason

Comment: You might want to mention you're also using m2e-android in your project.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, now added in above details.

Answer (score 0):

The sample program on page http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10 won't compile with 1.6.0-beta. But to tweak it I only needed to make two changes:

1. Change how ByteArrayContent is constructed.

```
HttpRequest request = rf.buildPostRequest(shortenEndpoint, new ByteArrayContent(requestBody));
```

Change it to

```
HttpRequest request = rf.buildPostRequest(shortenEndpoint, ByteArrayContent.fromString(null, requestBody));
```

2. Change the way to set content type.

```
request.headers.contentType = "application/json";
```

Change it to

```
request.getHeaders().setContentType("application/json");
```

I had to look into source code of 1.6.0-beta to figure this out. Google should publish 1.6.0-beta javadoc at least.